# Vitest Error : React refresh preamble was not loaded. Something is wrong

Tags: typescript, testing, vite, mern, vitest

I am new to testing and I was trying to use vitest for testing my mern social media app. looking for references to test a react component using vitest i found this article https://eternaldev.com/blog/testing-a-react-application-with-vitest. following this when i try to render a component i get the error **React refresh preamble was not loaded. Something is wrong on running tests** . below are relevant codes :

register.test.tsx

```
import { expect, test, describe } from 'vitest';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
// import Register from '../../components/Authentication/Register';
import Fake from '../../Fake';

describe('Registration Component Full functionality testing', () => {

    test("should be showing Signup heading", () => {

        render(<Fake />);
        expect(screen.getByText(/Fake/i)).toBeDefined()
    })
})
```

Fake.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

const Fake: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <div>Fake</div>
    )
}

export default Fake
```

vite.config.ts

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './setupTest.ts'
  }
})
```

I am open to share more information about my codebase if required . thanks.

I was trying to render a react component in a test coded using vitest but was getting the error **React refresh preamble was not loaded. Something is wrong** on doing so.
I am expecting any one who knows the answer to deliver a structured answer along with the explanation for what was missing or what was wrong .

Answer (score 8):

I have the same problem and I have tried both methods above but it doesn't work.

I found this discussion to help find a solution, [Running browser mode errors "@vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble"](https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/3283)

after I checked version 3 @vitejs/plugin-react, it turned out to have this bug.

the solution is quite easy

from :

```
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "3.0.1"
```

change to version 4+:

```
"@vitejs/plugin-react": "4.2.1"
```

Comment: Yep, I read all the articles and issue reports and everything. This is the thing that fixed it. THANK YOU!

Comment: had a similar issue with @vitejs/plugin-react-swc, updating it has helped

Comment: Worked for me as well. This should be marked as the solution. I read the documentation and they explained that v4.2.1 fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I see much the same with my component test ...

component is hr.tsx

```
export const Myhr = () => {
 return (
    <>
    <hr />
    </>
  )
};
```

Test program is

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

import { Myhr } from '../components/hr.tsx'

describe('myhr test', () => {
  it("should draw line", () => {
    const { findByTestId } = render(<Myhr />);
  })
})
```

I see ...

```
FAIL  src/__tests__/hr.test.tsx [ src/__tests__/hr.test.tsx ]
Error: @vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong. See https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/pull/11#discussion_r430879201
 ❯ src/components/hr.tsx:1:27
      1| export const Myhr = () => {
       |                           ^
      2|  return (
      3|     <>
 ❯ src/__tests__/hr.test.tsx:3:31
```

The linked discussion is closed - and of little relevance

My config ...

cat vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {'process.argv': process.argv}, 
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './setup.js',
  }
});
```

grep -v ^/ setup.js | grep -v '^$'

```
import { afterEach, describe, expect, it, test } from 'vitest'
import { cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import matchers from '@testing-library/jest-dom/matchers';
expect.extend(matchers);
afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
});
```

Today I ran the code again - after reinstalling `npm i @vitejs/plugin-react`

Today the previous error is gone - I know not why ....

Comment: I tried initiating a whole new project and that solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you! `npm i @vitejs/plugin-react` solved my problem as well, and I also don't know why :(

Answer (score 0):

most likely versions of the packages out of sync
update all vite and vitest packages to latest version, that should solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [bun](https://bun.sh/) for my package manager and it broke my complete vitest install.

Remove vitest and jsdom from `package.json` and delete `node_modules` folder. After that reinstall everything with either yarn or npm. This solved it for me.